# Posting to a REST interface

Tags: angularjs, rest

need to define the name as ID in the URL and need to post an object containing data.

$scope.dvModel.naam is the name that acts as the ID. 
filteredObject is the object containing the data, obviously.

This is how I call the service, seems ok according to some examples.

```
saveDVservice.query($scope.dvModel.naam, filteredObject);
```

This is the actual service.

```
.factory('saveDVservice', ['$resource', 'CONSTANTS', function($resource, CONSTANTS) {
    'use strict';
    return $resource(CONSTANTS.REST_BASE_URL + '/dv/:name', {}, { query: { method: 'POST', isArray: false, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }}});
}]);
```

This is what I see in my network tab at Query String Parameters:
0:A
1:D
10:n
11:h
12:i
13:l
14:f
15:e
2:A
3:C
4: 
5:P
6:a
7:n
8:n
9:e

Which is the name, but looks like an array.

Request Payload contains the actual object in correct order.
Can one give me some guidance on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to put `$scope.dvModel.naam` into URL and you want `filteredObject` to be a request payload. Then you need an object that contains everything that's in `filteredObject` and additionaly under the key `name` a value equal to `$scope.dvModel.naam`.

Also, the definition of your resource probably should change - in second argument `$resource` requires you to tell it the way of extracting URL data from given object:

```
$resource(CONSTANTS.REST_BASE_URL + '/dv/:name', {name: '@name'}, { query: { method: 'POST', isArray: false, headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }}});
```

Unfortunately, `$resource` isn't the best `$http` wrapper to use when your payload data is separated from URL data. Maybe it would be better to wrap the `filteredObject` data in payload in some other object? Then your `$resource` object would be much nicer, like `{name: ..., data: {"0": "A", "1": "D", ...}}`

Comment: when I follow this appproach i get this request URL based on a POST query: http://localhost:8000/dvb-service/dv?name=Touring+Club+Belgie

Comment: my bad, mix up between name and 'naam' (Dutch, It isnt my decission to use paramters in a Dutch way....). Now I have: http://localhost:8000/dvb-service/dv/Touring%20Club%20Belgie >> which is way better besides the %20, but thats not my problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since default action for `query` is `{method: 'GET', isArray: true}`, I'd leave that be and use another default, `save` instead. That should work out-of-the-box.

```
app.factory('DVService', function ($resource) {
  return $resource(CONSTANTS.REST_BASE_URL + '/dv', {name: '@name'}, {}); 
});
```

.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, DVService) {
  var postData = {
    name: 'name',
    fooProp: 'foo',
    barProp: 'bar'
  };

  // save/post        
  DVservice.save({dv: postData}).$promise.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });

  //query/get
  DVService.query({name: 'name'}).$promise.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Comment: makes sense, however, the url to save / POST to needs to end with tne 'name' as identifier. So how to POST the object AND build up the URL like this: ..../dv/theNameOftheIdentifier

Comment: ahh wait, name is already in the object you are describing, so that should be wired to {name: '@name'} in DVService

Comment: checked the request URL, and its: http://localhost:8000/dvb-service/dv >> so its missing the name part after 'dv'

Comment: Try `return $resource(CONSTANTS.REST_BASE_URL + '/dv/:name', {name: '@name'}, {});`

Comment: yeah already sort of fixed it, based on Patryk his awnser, but both of you showed me the correct vote. I accepted his awnser but upvoted you as well. thx